# Convert Scala ListBuffer to JSON via Case Class using Play JSON API

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

I have a case class defined as `case class IndexList(value: ListBuffer[String])`
I'm unable to convert this to JSON using Play API.

I've tried

```
object IndexList{
  implicit val indexListWrites = Json.writes[IndexList]
}
```

as part of Macro Inception but it fails giving compilation error:

```
exception during macro expansion:
[error] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.tl$1()Lscala/collection/immutable/List;
```

I've also tried

```
object IndexList{
  implicit val indexListWrites: Writes[IndexList] = Writes{
    (indexList: IndexList) => JsArray(indexList.value)
  }
}
```

but fails with error:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]
[error]  required: Seq[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]
```

Any help regarding either of the methods would be helpful.
If there are other ways to accomplish this, it's fine as well.

Comment: I tried ```implicit val indexListWrites: OWrites[IndexList] = Json.writes[IndexList]``` and it compiled just fine

Comment: try this instead: ```implicit val indexListWrites: Writes[IndexList] = Writes[IndexList](il => Json.toJson(il.value))```